# Metricbeat Apache dashboard is not showing visualizations. "Could not locate that index-pattern"

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, kibana, metricbeat

I have a web server running metricbeat and have successfully set up the Metricbeat System default dashboards. I can't seem to get the [Metricbeat Apache] Overview dashboard to work though. All of the areas where visualizations should be displayed have a red triangle with an "!" inside and an error such as:

> Could not locate that index-pattern (id: metricbeat-*), click here to re-create it

I cannot click the text which says "click here to re-create it". It is not a clickable object.

I enabled the apache module with the following command:

```
metricbeat modules enable apache
```

I had previously set up the dashboards using:

```
metricbeat setup --dashboards
```

I checked the metricbeat log file at /var/log/metricbeat/metricbeat but there were no errors. How can I make the Metricbeat Apache visualizations for the default dashboard display correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

In my case, I did not have Apache's "server-status" module set up correctly. And since metricbeat's apache module depends on this, it was not working.

I fixed this by making sure I had access to http://www.example.com/server-status
page

To do this I changed (in .htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On
```

to:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

Once I did that, the dashboard started working.